# Magento Cron Tab Job Time zone

Tags: php, linux, magento, cron

Im trying to figure out if my module cron is running at the correct time.

The cron for my module is set at 1am (0 1 * * *), the time zone of the default store is Western Europe (Paris, Berlin etc GMT +2), the server time is EDT (Eastern Daylight Time).

So on which time zone is the 1am schedule based on?

Thanks,

Comment: @Fiasco Labs has the correct answer here.  The data you have in the XML file is used for scheduling and is in the default TZ you have configured for your store.  All dispatch and storage of the scheduled jobs in the DB is under UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Magento cron process runs under the UTC timezone.

This can be verified by temporarily adding a small log statement to the cron observer.

The method is:

```
Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::dispatch()
```

Look for this code in the first few lines:

```
$now = time();
```

Either right before or after, add this:

```
Mage::log("cron timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get(), Zend_Log::DEBUG);
```

Then check your var/log/system.log file and you will see that PHP/Magento is using the UTC timezone.

Comment: As pointed out by @Fiasco Labs, the scheduling INPUT is treated as a default configured TZ value, not UTC.  So, while everything is scheduled and dispatched AS UTC, the input data is treated with a possible TZ offset.

Comment: Many thanks guys for your knowledge! So, as I understand it, my 1am cron time will be 1am based on the store time? This is exactly what I want!

Comment: In regards to Mag::log, am I correct guessing that the log timestamps are always GMT? The times are 2 hours behind my scheduled cron time so this would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The Magento cron job log times are recorded in UTC. Actual run times are based off the TZ offset (server time). Here's a Cron Job Monitor script that shows you the jobs as they're scheduled and then their completion times. It also gives you UTC, the server time and your store time (single store). All three can be different.
[Cron Job Monitor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/351010/)

For it to be useful, I set System Config to keep errors and logged information for 24 hours. That way you can actually monitor the big jobs that run in the early AM and confirm they're really running.

Comment: catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all success 2011-09-29 08:45:05 2011-09-29 09:00:00 2011-09-29 09:00:05 2011-09-29 09:00:13 Not according to observed log times. This is set to run at 2:00AM every morning which checks out against the clock. Here's its cron entry Catalog  catalog/product_indexer_price:: reindexAll  0 2 * * * Note that it's recorded as having run at 9:00AM This is on 1.4.1.1, so not sure what's going on with 1.5.1.x

Comment: Everything might happen in UTC, but it's shifted to the local time zone for actual Run Time. Otherwise you'd have some really hefty processes running during your store's busy hours. I extended this cron monitor out after having someone tell me that Magento scheduled and RAN everything by UTC. How does that compare with what you're saying?

Comment: After looking deeper into the scheduling code I have found the part that does indeed use the configured default timezone for the install.  My mistake was overlooking a call to Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->timestamp($time)

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, Lee. It was a source of frustration about six months ago trying to find out exactly when things were running (usual misery of getting cron jobs to fire) and no documentation to fall back on. :^) I actually sat up one night to watch the large jobs start firing off at 2:00AM. Not the only late night Magento's caused! Every delving in and explanation helps.

Comment: Well, for future reference, the method that does the 'magic' is: Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::trySchedule() and the 'magic' looks like this: $d = getdate(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->timestamp($time));